# JavaScript innerHTML is not working for IE?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I am using ajax call for to bring the list for my drop down and assign it to html,works fine for mozilla nad crome but for IE it displays a  blank dropdown

```
var xmlhttp;

var strURL = "selectedu.php?selectward="+selectward;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        if(xmlhttp.responseText=="NOER")
        {
            alert("Select ER Type");
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }   
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",strURL,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Can you post some more code for this? If possible try http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: can you detail: which tagName is your element and, how you create and make your XHR call ?

Comment: ...and here we see the StackOverflowers in their natural habitat. Hungry for code they quickly swarm the new questions and poke and prod until the questioner has excreted every last iota of script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `innerHTML` property has some problems in IE when trying to add or update form elements, the workaround is to create a div and set the innerHtml property on that before appending to the DOM:

```
var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
newdiv.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
var container = document.getElementById(id);
container.appendChild(newdiv);
```

Answer (score 4):

If the document is XHTML the IE will not allow the `innerHTML` property to be set directly. You would need to parse the `responseText` into DOM elements and replace the contents of the existing element with those elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery you can use `append()` like this:

```
$get('yourTargetObjectId').append('<p>this test to add</p>');
```

`append()` inserts content at the end of the selected element and use `prepend()` to insert at the beginning of the selected element.