# Onclick doesn't work as expected on tr

Tags: javascript, onclick, html-table

I'm trying to make the `onclick` event work for all rows of a table. But, it doesn't matter what row I click, the event only seems to fire for the last `tr`. I made a simple example to illustrate the problem on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5xoh84r/).

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName( "table" )[0];
for( var contador = 0; contador < table.getElementsByTagName( "tr" ).length; contador++ ){
  var line = table.getElementsByTagName( "tr" )[contador];
  line.onclick = function() {
    line.innerHTML = "Row clicked";
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is  a scoping issue, `for` block doesn't create a new scope, so the last value overrides the previous values, you can use a self-invoking function:

```
(function (line) {
    line.onclick = function () {
        //line.innerHTML = "Row clicked";
        line.cells[0].textContent = "Row clicked";
     };
})(table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[contador]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tx3s580a/

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in undefined's answer, for block doesn't create a new scope.

`line` gets changed every time the loop is run. Use `this` instead...

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName( "table" )[0];
for( var contador = 0; contador < table.getElementsByTagName( "tr" ).length; contador++ ){
    var line = table.getElementsByTagName( "tr" )[contador];
    line.onclick = function(){
        this.innerHTML = "Row clicked...";
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a9xf0nz2/

Answer (score 0):

Others replied faster than me, but once you have fixed your issue, also pay attention to the fact that your "innerHTML" will probably not work correctly with IE (your jsfiddle gives a 
"SCRIPT600: Invalid target element for this operation" in mine)!

[JavaScript innerHTML is not working for IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999998/javascript-innerhtml-is-not-working-for-ie)