# PHP Populate dropdown with ajax onchange issue IE Only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having a heck of a time with this issue.  I'm simply trying to populate a second dropdown based on the choice of the first using jquery ajax.  It works great in every other browser, including Edge, just not IE 11.

Here's the ajax function

```
    function getProfiles(val) {
   $.ajax({
     cache: false,
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'ajaxDept.php?dept=' + val,
     data: {
       get_option:val
     },
     success: function (response) {
       document.getElementById("comboprofile").innerHTML=response; 
     }

   });
}
```

This is the ajaxDept.php code

```
<?php
include('/inc/config.inc.php');

$dbAjax = new Database();
$dbAjax->connect();
$dbAjax->selectDB('cad');
$dept = $_GET['dept'];

$queryAjax = $dbAjax->SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE department='".$dept."' ORDER BY profile_prefix ASC");
foreach($queryAjax as $line)
{
    $prefix = $line['profile_prefix'];
    $profile = $prefix."-".$line['profile_name'];
    $department = $line['department'];
    echo "<option value='".$prefix."'>".$profile."</option>";
}
?>
```

And the HTML portion

```
  <label class="description" for="comboDept">Department</label>
  <div>
    <select class="element select medium" id="comboDept" name="comboDept" onchange="getProfiles(this.value);">
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
      <?php echo $comboDept; ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</li>
<li id="li_13">
  <label class="description" for="comboprofile">Profile</label>
  <div>
    <select class="element select medium" id="comboprofile" name="comboprofile">

    </select>
  </div>
</li>
```

I've run through the debugger with IE 11 and I'm getting a 200/OK

This is the request URL as IE sees it, which is correct

Request URL: http://php/CAD/new/ajaxDept.php?dept=IT

When I browse to that url in IE, and view source, it's showing me the correct html code with the `<option>` tags.  It's simply not populating my dropdown.

Again, works perfectly well in every other browser I've tried, so I'm not sure this is actually a jQuery/Ajax issue or something with how IE is handling the HTML response.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the `dataType` parameter to `"html"` in your ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *might* be because of this line according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9000029/1022914):

```
document.getElementById("comboprofile").innerHTML=response;
```

Since you are using jQuery, you might as well keep using it by replacing that line with:

```
$('#comboprofile').html(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mikey, that was the fix.

**$('#comboprofile').html(response);**

This was the final working function

```
function getProfiles(val) {
   $.ajax({
     cache: false,
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'ajaxDept.php?dept=' + val,
     data: {
       get_option:val
     },
     success: function (response) {
       $('#comboprofile').html(response); 
     }

   });
}
```